# Why is the same command different when stored to variable vs output to stdout?

Tags: bash, text, sed

I am working with an output as follows within:

```
OUTPUT="VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  VAL4" #(two spaces between each VAL)
```

I'm trying to store the output in a variable SAMPLE as such to replace double spaces as commas, as run in the script:

```
SAMPLE=$(echo $OUTPUT | sed 's/\ \ /\,/g'); echo $SAMPLE
```

returns `VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 VAL4` (one space between each val)

Yet if I run it in without storing it to a variable I get a different output

`echo $OUTPUT | sed 's/\ \ /\,/g')` returns `VAL1,VAL2,VAL3,VAL4` as desired

Comment: Why are you backslash-escaping whitespace inside single quotes?

Comment: Did you actually write `somecmd | sed 's/\ \ /\,/g'` but replaced it with `echo $OUTPUT | sed 's/\ \ /\,/g'` for the purpose of this question? You'll find that this broke it (due to word splitting mentioned in the answer). Always test your test case.

Comment: @n.m. Damn it, you're right, it's been a long day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule, you should always quote variables in bash to preserve formatting (unless you have some specific reason for not using quotes, e.g. want expansion, want to do something hackish like limit to one space using `echo $variable`, inside `[[]]` (optional), etc...)

```
$ echo $OUTPUT 
VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 VAL4" 
$ echo "$OUTPUT" 
VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  VAL4

$ SAMPLE=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | sed 's/\ \ /\,/g'); echo "$SAMPLE"
VAL1,VAL2,VAL3,VAL4
```

`echo $OUTPUT | sed 's/\ \ /\,/g'` should not result in a comma seperated list (without quoting `$OUTPUT`), unless you have some weird `echo`/`shell`.

Also, it may not be the best convention to use caps variable names in bash, since they're mostly just used for internal variables (e.g. `$PWD`)

Comment: After I submitted I remembered the quotes to preserve formatting. And I'm not using caps in script, I just did question to make them stand out.

Comment: You're partly right about the case of variable names. The convention is that all-caps are used for environment variables (`$HOME`, `$PATH`, etc.). Of course, many of the built-in variables are also environment variables.  If you are creating your own environment variables, it is conventional to use upper-case names.  For script-local variables, lower-case is the norm.